# OpenSsl: how to create PFX/P12 without including CA files?

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, p12

I have a trusted certificate chain, a certificate issued by this chain and private key file for this certificate.

I want to create a P12 / PFX for this, so I can put it as client certificate in the windows store:

```
OpenSsl Pkcs12 -export -nokeys
               -certfile mytrustedCertifcates.pem^
               -inkey myPrivateKey.Key^
               -in myCertificate.crt^
               -out myCertificate.P12
```

Alas, the resulting file contains all trustedCertificates. If I import the P12 in my windows certificate store, I import the complete certificate chain, although they are already in the certificate store.

I also tried options: (from [OpenSsl command line utilities](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Command_Line_Utilities#Client_Certificates_AKA_pkcs12), also in -help)

- -nocerts don't output certificates.
- -clcerts only output client certificates.

Alas, the P12 still contains the complete certificate chain, and importing the P12 imports the complete chain again.

Comment: Presumably just remove the `-certfile mytrustedCertificates.pem` altogether... `-in` is the cert that matches `-inkey`, if you don't want anything else... just don't provide it?

Comment: BartonJs: So simple! Because in most other commands I used I had to include the certificate authorities. Apparently that is not needed for a P12 / PFX

Answer (score 1):

BartonJs gave the answer in a comment (thank you BartonJs!):

leave out the --certfile parameter:

```
OpenSsl Pkcs12 -export -nokeys
               -name some friendly name
               -inkey myPrivateKey.Key^
               -in myCertificate.crt^
               -out myCertificate.P12
```

- nokeys: leaves out the PEM password
- name: the friendly name that will appear in column friendly name of the winstore
- inkey and in are the input certficate with its private key
- out is the name of the file to produce.

After importing it in the windstore (command: certlm.msc), It propertly says:

- Issued to:
- Issued by:
- Expiration date
- Intended purposes
- Friendly name: